# How do I navigate inside a web page when web scraping?

Tags: web-scraping

I need to scrape data from this webpage - https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/693771.Ignited_Minds.

I am using beautifulsoup, how do I get the comments from the second comments section inside the comment box?

Comment: What have you tried? Post some of your code

Comment: It is an on-click event:<a rel="next" href="#" onclick="new Ajax.Request('/book/reviews/693771.Ignited_Minds?authenticity_token=mQKFjSPqDSyCP9AcLnYUB6lA7ty1p1xi%2FpcE91Jj1UbnFSo5x6SnSXTD51SEJ864Txhnj2jp6Pp%2B%2F0hVWkSr0w%3D%3D&amp;amp;hide_last_page=true&amp;amp;page=4', {asynchronous:true, evalScripts:true, method:'get', parameters:'authenticity_token=' + encodeURIComponent('W4pFqkgt7mMAKsOv13MyyyVC9uVd9p5r3cf96fiFyJAlneoerGNEBvbW9Od9Iuh0wxp/toC4KvNdr7FL8KK2BQ==')}); return false;">4</a>

Comment: Need to navigate to this link and get the data

Comment: In that case, you need to look into Selenium

Comment: Selenium is very slow when you need to parse large amounts of data

Comment: On inspecting element, i get the follow url for the next page as:

Request URL: https://www.goodreads.com/book/reviews/693771.Ignited_Minds?authenticity_token=MzPuylLRQ5brNiwr6W9U3Kc155EXNYt%2F1Bxt3SC0xST9kpwvuDwOKFEFLbzLHDMnAl%2BFQOO3SELaHnt%2B2mFCbw%3D%3D&amp;hide_last_page=true&amp;page=3&authenticity_token=KJ3XcbMc8gOXcK5yGt59tQkGBmsPxeQRL9QrrFH4Mm7mPKWUWfG%2FvS1Dr%2BU4rRpOrGxkuvtHJywh1j0Pqy21JQ%3D%3D

and also the response content for this URL.

Comment: But how do i look for the response content?